# In what ratio does the intersection point divide the line segments?

Tags: java, swing

What I made:

- I drew X and Y Axises and my segments;
- I wrote a code, that returns true if the segments intersect.
- I wrote a code, that returns the coordinate of an intersection point.

But how I can calculate a ratio does the intersection point divide line segments?

Thanks a lot for your help. ^^

My code is:

```
package com.staaankey;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Cartesian {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CartesianFrame frame = new CartesianFrame();
                frame.showUI();
            }
        });
    }

}

class CartesianFrame extends JFrame {
    CartesianPanel panel;

    public CartesianFrame() {
        panel = new CartesianPanel();
        add(panel);
    }

    public void showUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Main");
        setSize(700, 700);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CartesianPanel extends JPanel {
    // x-axis coord constants
    public static final int X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD = 50;
    public static final int X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD = 600;
    public static final int X_AXIS_Y_COORD = 600;

    // y-axis coord constants
    public static final int Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD = 50;
    public static final int Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD = 600;
    public static final int Y_AXIS_X_COORD = 50;

    //arrows of axis are represented with "hipotenuse" of
    //triangle
    // now we are define length of cathetas of that triangle
    public static final int FIRST_LENGHT = 10;
    public static final int SECOND_LENGHT = 5;

    // size of start coordinate lenght
    public static final int ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT = 6;

    // distance of coordinate strings from axis
    public static final int AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE = 20;


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // x-axis
        g2.drawLine(X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD, X_AXIS_Y_COORD,
                X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD, X_AXIS_Y_COORD);
        // y-axis
        g2.drawLine(Y_AXIS_X_COORD, Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD,
                Y_AXIS_X_COORD, Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD);

        // x-axis arrow
        g2.drawLine(X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD - FIRST_LENGHT,
                X_AXIS_Y_COORD - SECOND_LENGHT,
                X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD, X_AXIS_Y_COORD);
        g2.drawLine(X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD - FIRST_LENGHT,
                X_AXIS_Y_COORD + SECOND_LENGHT,
                X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD, X_AXIS_Y_COORD);

        // y-axis arrow
        g2.drawLine(Y_AXIS_X_COORD - SECOND_LENGHT,
                Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD + FIRST_LENGHT,
                Y_AXIS_X_COORD, Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD);
        g2.drawLine(Y_AXIS_X_COORD + SECOND_LENGHT,
                Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD + FIRST_LENGHT,
                Y_AXIS_X_COORD, Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD);

        // draw origin Point
        g2.fillOval(
                X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD - (ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT / 2),
                Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT / 2),
                ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT, ORIGIN_COORDINATE_LENGHT);

        // draw text "X" and draw text "Y"
        g2.drawString("X", X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD - AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE / 2,
                X_AXIS_Y_COORD + AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE);
        g2.drawString("Y", Y_AXIS_X_COORD - AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE,
                Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD + AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE / 2);
        g2.drawString("(0, 0)", X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD - AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE,
                Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD + AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE);

        // numerate axis
        int xCoordNumbers = 10;
        int yCoordNumbers = 10;
        int xLength = (X_AXIS_SECOND_X_COORD - X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD)
                / xCoordNumbers;
        int yLength = (Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - Y_AXIS_FIRST_Y_COORD)
                / yCoordNumbers;

        // draw x-axis numbers
        for(int i = 1; i < xCoordNumbers; i++) {
            g2.drawLine(X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (i * xLength),
                    X_AXIS_Y_COORD - SECOND_LENGHT,
                    X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (i * xLength),
                    X_AXIS_Y_COORD + SECOND_LENGHT);
            g2.drawString(Integer.toString(i),
                    X_AXIS_FIRST_X_COORD + (i * xLength) - 3,
                    X_AXIS_Y_COORD + AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE);
        }

        //draw y-axis numbers
        for(int i = 1; i < yCoordNumbers; i++) {
            g2.drawLine(Y_AXIS_X_COORD - SECOND_LENGHT,
                    Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (i * yLength),
                    Y_AXIS_X_COORD + SECOND_LENGHT,
                    Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (i * yLength));
            g2.drawString(Integer.toString(i),
                    Y_AXIS_X_COORD - AXIS_STRING_DISTANCE,
                    Y_AXIS_SECOND_Y_COORD - (i * yLength));
        }

        //draw first section
        int fX1 = 125;
        int fY1 = 75;
        int fX2 = 135;
        int fY2 = 75;
        g2.drawLine(fX1, fY1, fX2, fY2);

        //draw second section
        int sX1 = 130;
        int sY1 = 50;
        int sX2 = 140;
        int sY2 = 150;

        g2.drawLine(sX1, sY1, sX2, sY2);

        int v1 = (sX2 - sX1) * (fY1 - sY1) - (sY2 - sY1) * (fX1 - sX1);

        int v2 = (sX2 - sX1) * (fY2 - sX1) - (sY2 - sY1) * (fX2 - sX1);

        int v3 = (fX2 - fX1) *(sY1 - fY1) - (fY2 - fY1) * (sX1 - fX1);

        int v4 = (fX2 - fX1) * (sY2 - fY1) - (fY2 - fY1) * (sX2 - fX1);

        Boolean result;

        if((v1 * v2 < 0) && (v3 * v4 < 0)){
            result = true;
        }
        else{
            result = false;
        }
        System.out.println(result);

        int detL1 = det(fX1, fY1, fX2, fY2);
        int detL2 = det(sX1, sY1, sX2, sY2);
        int x1mx2 = fX1 - fX2;
        int x3mx4 = sX1 - sX2;
        int y1my2 = fY1 - fY2;
        int y3my4 = sY1 - sY2;

        int denom = det(x1mx2, y1my2, x3mx4, y3my4);
        if(denom == 0){
            return;
        }
        int xnom = det(detL1 ,x1mx2, detL2, x3mx4);
        int ynom = det(detL1, y1my2, detL2, y3my4);
        int ixOut = xnom / denom;
        int iYOut = ynom / denom;
        System.out.println("ixOut: ");
        System.out.println("iYOut: ");
        System.out.println(ixOut);;
        System.out.println(iYOut);
    }

    public int det(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        return x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't there a formula for there in Maths? Section formula I guess.

Comment: What ratio are you talking about?  The ratio of both segments of the same line?  The ratio of the smaller segment of one line to the larger segment of the other?  The ration of the smaller segment of one line to the smaller segment of the other. 
 And so forth.  In any event, use the distance formula to get the lengths of the required line segments and compute a ratio.

Comment: @WJS Probably, I'm talking about the ratio of both segments of the same line.

Comment: @AKSingh I tried to google something in java about it or in another programming language. But i found only a formula for bisectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the distance formula, `Math.hypot()` to calculate the length of the segments.  That would be from one end of the line (it's x,y location) to the intersection point.  Then from the other lines x,y location to the intersection point.  Then divide the smaller length by the larger length.  Make certain you use floating point math for the result.

Example:

```
// some arbitrary line with slope = 5 and y-intercept = 23
UnaryOperator<Integer> y = x->5*x + 23; 
int endx = 2;
int endy = y.apply(endx);

int otherendx = 10;
int otherendy = y.apply(otherendx);

int intx = 5;
int inty = y.apply(intx);

double seg1Length = Math.hypot(endx-intx, endy - inty);
double seg2Length = Math.hypot(otherendx-intx, otherendy - inty);

double ratio = Math.min(seg1Length,seg2Length)/Math.max(seg1Length,seg2Length);
```

prints

```
Ratio = 0.6
```

Comment: That's probably a way for me. Thanks. ^^